# How to add random offset to sine time in Unity's Shader Graph?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I have created a shader using Unity's shaderGraph to move my clouds back and forth. I'm using Sine Time to alter the x-position of all the pixels in my sprite. Now, all the clouds are moving in sync, but I'd like to have them move a little more random.

In ShaderGraph, I'm trying to offset the sine wave by adding a random number to it, but it does not work the way I expect it to. Instead of having random movement, all the clouds change their starting position. I am probably going about it the wrong way. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

I have added my attempt in the table below.

| What | Screenshot from ShaderGraph |
| --- | --- |
| Change position using Sine Time. All clouds moving in sync | [image: default] |
| Try to add offset with random range using the object's x-position as seed. All clouds moving in sync, but start position is changed | [image: add random range] |

**Here are the clouds floating in my game**

[image: floating skies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your random value to the time value (not sine time), then send that *summed* result to a sine function in its own graph node.

You can also optionally multiply that (time+random) input value by a randomized scale to make some clouds move with a different period.

Comment: It makes sense now, after studying the difference.

I struggled to keep the clouds moving randomly even with this solution. Because copying the object in the scene, and then changing the position didn't seem to work. Creating a new object on the other hand did the trick. I wonder if this is a bug in my Unity version, or if there's a minor thing I have overlooked. I'm not sure. Anyway, it works now, and thanks for the extra tip!

Comment: [This could be due to dynamic batching](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/143205/39518) - you can disable batching on this material and see if that makes a difference, though at a slight performance cost if you have a lot of these.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment. Yes, it looks like it can be a batching thing. I haven't figured where to disable this in Shader Graph, but someone in this forum thread, https://forum.unity.com/threads/shader-graph-object-position-node-is-wrong-on-multiple-objects.744917/, suggested to create a new material through script instead, which seemed to do the trick.